# tomcat asking continously for authentication login

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I am new in this environment and did all settings and configuration of manager-gui but asking ontinously for authentication login. I do not know the reason. Any idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check users config file under conf folder

Comment: This is not enough information. Which environment? Which settings? Whos asking? When?

Comment: once changed did you restart the server?

Comment: like said by prasad i think u shd restart at first then check. could be because of proxy settings. are u using proxy net like university somewhere?

Comment: aah yes i was using proxy net, thanks for pointing, bcz at home there was no such problem... thanks